# spring cloud config become my single point of failure

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Briefly, can i run a Spring Cloud Config server cluster to ensure high availability? If yes, how?

I'm trying to use Spring Cloud Config as my central config service. My problem is that each client can only specify one server to fetch config. If this server is down, everything has to wait for its recovery.

Some other framework allows you to run several servers and enumerate them on the client side. Does Spring Cloud Config has such feature?

If that's not possible, I'm considering run several instances and put them behind nginx. Can that cause some side effect?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did u solve this issue? what approach u used finally to have a fail-safe config server

Answer (score 1):

> Some other framework allows you to run several servers and enumerate them on the client side. Does Spring Cloud Config has such feature?

You should use [Spring Cloud Netflix Eureka](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-eureka-server.html) to include Eureka Server as service discovery and include the [Eureka Client](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html#_service_discovery_eureka_clients) in services(Microservice).
you can have the Config Server register with the Discovery Service.

[Spring Cloud Config Discovery service](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#discovery-first-bootstrap)

from document :

> If you use a DiscoveryClient implementation, such as Spring Cloud Netflix and Eureka Service Discovery or Spring Cloud Consul, you can have the Config Server register with the Discovery Service. However, in the default “Config First” mode, clients cannot take advantage of the registration.
>
> If you prefer to use DiscoveryClient to locate the Config Server, you can do so by setting spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=true (the default is false). The net result of doing so is that client applications all need a bootstrap.yml (or an environment variable) with the appropriate discovery configuration. For example, with Spring Cloud Netflix, you need to define the Eureka server address (for example, in eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone). The price for using this option is an extra network round trip on startup, to locate the service registration. The benefit is that, as long as the Discovery Service is a fixed point, the Config Server can change its coordinates. The default service ID is configserver, but you can change that on the client by setting spring.cloud.config.discovery.serviceId (and on the server, in the usual way for a service, such as by setting spring.application.name).

for example `bootstrap.yml` in services(clients):

```
spring:
  application:
    name: example-service
  cloud:
    config:
      fail-fast: true
      discovery:
        enabled: true
        service-id: configuration-server
# Eureka client
eureka:
  client:
    prefer-same-zone-eureka: true
    region: region1
    service-url:
      zone1: http://discovery-server-01:8761/eureka/,http://discovery-server-02:8761/eureka/
    availability-zones:
      region1: zone1
```